# How to generate random variable from a shifted (right or left doesnt matter) from a distribution in R?

Tags: r, distribution

My attempt:

```
g1 <- rt(10,3) #generating random samples fron a t3 distribution 
g2 <- rt(10,3)-2 # g2 = g1(x-2) ,Normally so but this is false
```

I just want to know how to shift a t distribution .i am not saying my code is true

Comment: to generate `normal` random variables that are shifted, scalled, `rnorm(10, mean= 3)` this is shifted to the right by 3. For a t distribution, you could use the `rt.scaled` from the `metRology` package